# the file should be not saved after ctrl C?

Tags: linux, shell, filesystems, dd

I want to prove that "the data block is ensured to be completely saved in non volatile storage, if interrupted, no data block is saved)"

I did it like this

```
# on a ext4 filesystem 
rm /mnt/my_file.txt -rf 
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/mnt/my_file.txt count=1000 bs=1024k oflag=direct
# press ctrl C,or kill dd
```

I expect there is no /mnt/my_file.txt created,or I mis-understand something ?

Comment: I think you mean "the filesystem removing files when their write operation is interrupted". By the time you get around to pressing Ctrl-C, the file will already been partially written. Removing partially written files would, however, be not really desirable in the general case... please clarify what behavior exactly you are looking for.

Comment: I am still not sure why you think the file system *should* behave like you described. A program that is interrupted terminates. Upon termination, existing streams are flushed and closed. Why do you think the partially written file (of which the file system has no idea it *was* only partial) should be removed? If anything, it would be the writing program's responsibility to trap Ctrl-C and remove partially written data before terminating, if that is indeed desired. I don't see why this would be an issue of the file system.